# Is there a method to get the value of key in ruby and store it in a variable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the value of a key and trying to store it in an array

Below is the sample code,

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'json'

opt=[]


response_assigned = {
    "poll_id": 1194

}

opt << [JSON.parse(response_assigned)['poll_id']]
```

By using ruby, I have tried to convert `poll_id` variable into string,

```
opt << [JSON.parse(response_assigned)['poll_id'].to_s,channel_id]
```

but it is throwing same error.

> 'convert_encoding': {:poll_id=>1194} is not like a string (TypeError)

Comment: Are you talking about something like `Hash#key()`or `Hash#keys` ?

Comment: in the example your `response_assigned` is a ruby hash and not a JSON object -- which would cause a type error when using `JSON.parse`. I would double check the type your actual code is giving for `response_assigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response_assigned` is already a `Hash`. You can access the values via `:[]`; there's no need to use `JSON.parse` here. (This method is used for converting JSON **string**s into hashes, like the object you already have!)

Also, a more subtle note: There are two distinct types of object in ruby: [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) and [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html).

By defining your object like this: `{"poll_id": 1194}`, you have made the hash key a **symbol**. It's equivalent to writing this: `{poll_id: 1194}`, or this: `{:poll_id => 1194}`.

Therefore, in order to access the value, you can use:

```
opt << response_assigned[:poll_id]
```

---

If you want to make the hash key a `String` instead of a `Symbol`, you could write:

```
response_assigned = {
  "poll_id" => 1194
}

opt << response_assigned["poll_id"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and prompt explanation.... i have an api which gives me the result like this after creating a poll in the ui

```
{
    "poll_id": 1194

}
```

I am planning to only the poll_id and store it in array in opt.... can you pls help me on how can i do that

Comment: Is there something missing from my explanation? If the above code does not work, can you please show the error?

Comment: It worked Tom .... thanks for ur support ...i tried in the same way which u told ,,,